# How to pass boolean value to stored procedure in java

Tags: java, entitymanager, jpa-2.1

I have a procedure with parameter IN type BOOLEAN

```
create or replace procedure p(count_in in int, enabled_in in BOOLEAN) is
BEGIN   
 ...
END;
```

I tried to call this procedure from Java JPA with Entity Manager. Java code below

```
StoredProcedureQuery proc = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("p");
proc.registerStoredProcedureParameter(count_in, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(enabled_in, Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN)
...
```

I got error message:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of
> arguments in call to 'p' ...

The problem is the second BOOLEAN parameter. The question is:

How to pass a boolean value to the stored procedure in java?

Thanks

Comment: Is the typo `BBOLEAN` the source of the problem?

Comment: sorry, it's a real typo, corrected, Not the source of the problem. thanks.